# WPF Attach VisualState to Object Property

Tags: wpf, blend, visualstatemanager

I am working on expression Blend for VS2015, I have a`ListBox` binded to an `ObservableCollection` of custom objects. Those objects expose `Properties` that arise the `NotifyPropertyChanged`, and everything works nice.

I can bind parts if the `ItemTemplate` to those `Properties` and my list work nice but what I want to do is to set the `VisualState` according to a certain `bool` (already configured or not). I also created some events (configured, confLost) and tried to target those events in the triggers panel but .. nothing worked.

How do I bind `VisualStates` to members of the bound object ??

Comment: Hi Javirs, Can you post your object class code? Or a snippet of it. I'll be able to help you then

Comment: @Master as shown in my answer, code to the object was not needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Kylo's solution would provably work, the people at Microsoft already worked a code-free, 3-clicks-away solution for such a simple action to do.

Solution is on Behaviors, there is one behavior called `GoToStateAction` you have to add one of them to your control and there you can set your trigger (that can be set as DataTrigger). In my case I binded to a property of the type enum.
Then you can set the Comparison and the value (equals to "ReadyToUse")

Then as an outcome of the comparison you can trigger a state change for a particular object, you set your object, and you select the state from a nice combobox. There is even a checbox for using your transitions.

[image: VS screenshot]

Comment: nice... you should also post the code that is changed after these... that is the actual key.

Answer (score 2):

`ItemTemplate` property works like any other `DependencyProperty`, it can be set/reset anytime and it's visual impact will be reflected on `UI`. see below example where I have bound a `bool` value to `ToggleButton` state and `ItemControl's` `ItemTemplate` is changed accordingly rendering different ***`visual`***.

**Update:** I designed a `Device` class that has device name and it's state to make a similar situation. And another class `MyVisualStateManager` to create a bindable property. Cause `VisualStateManager` class doesn't expose any property to bind directly. code is as below:

***XMAL***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflowTempProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"  Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackOverflowTempProject"
    >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding list}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1  DataContext="{Binding Name}" Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2">
                    <local:UserControl1.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.DeviceState}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="local:MyVisualStateManager.VisualState" Value="State1" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.DeviceState}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="local:MyVisualStateManager.VisualState" Value="State2" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </local:UserControl1.Style>
                </local:UserControl1>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

***UserControl:***

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfStackOverflowTempProject.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>        
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>            
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">                
            <VisualState x:Name="State1">                    
                <Storyboard>                        
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:2" Storyboard.TargetName="State1Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />                        
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:3" Storyboard.TargetName="State2Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />                        
                </Storyboard>                    
            </VisualState>                
            <VisualState x:Name="State2">                    
                <Storyboard>                        
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:3" Storyboard.TargetName="State1Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />                        
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:2" Storyboard.TargetName="State2Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />                        
                </Storyboard>                    
            </VisualState>                
        </VisualStateGroup>            
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>        
    <Border Name="State2Panel" Background="Green" Opacity="0"/>        
    <Border Name="State1Panel" Background="Red" Opacity="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>        
</Grid>
```

***DataContext:***

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        list = new List<Device>();
        list.Add(new Device() {Name="Device 1",DeviceState = 0 });
        list.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device 2", DeviceState = 1 });
        list.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device 3", DeviceState = 0 });
        list.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device 4", DeviceState = 2 });
        list.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device 5", DeviceState = 1 });
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Device> list { get; set; }

}

public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set 
        { 
            name = value;
            updateProperty("Name");
        }
    }
    private int deviceState;

    public int DeviceState
    {
        get { return deviceState; }
        set 
        { 
            deviceState = value;
            updateProperty("DeviceState");
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void updateProperty(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

***Helper Class:*** This class exposes an attached property `VisualState` that could be bound to any value in `xaml`.

```
public class MyVisualStateManager
{        
    public static string GetVisualState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(VisualStateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetVisualState(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for VisualState.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisualState", typeof(string), typeof(MyVisualStateManager), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(VisualStateChanged)));

    public static void VisualStateChanged(DependencyObject Do, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            string state = e.NewValue.ToString();
            var control = Do as FrameworkElement;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, state, true);
        }
    }
}
```

***Output***

***`Different Item representing different devices and visual is changed on basis of their`Devicestate`property which causes a`Trigger`to get executed in`UserControl1`.`***

[image: list Item]

Comment: any clue on how to do it from expression blend interface? by the way what I wanna do is change the VisualState of each one of the Items separately according to the bool on its particular object, But I guess is easy to inference from your example how to get there. Can you give some details on how to do that from expression Blend interface ?

Comment: @javirs in expression blend... you mean by reading that bool value from some config?

Comment: I mean in the user interface of Blend, where to click to get the conditional working, the switching between VisualStates (with the defined animation) depending on a Data variable. So far I'm not editing the xaml at all, just using Blend panels. And things are quite ok. I'd like to keep doing that.

Comment: @javirs when you said "by the way what I wanna do is change the VisualState of each one of the Items separately according to the bool" you mean that you want to set the visual of every item separately in your ListBox. i.e. first item in the list can have different visual then the second item of listbox depending on this bool value. Am I right?

Comment: @javirs For "where to click to get the conditional working" point. I'll update the answer altogether once you clear my above point.

Comment: exactly, I have one entry in the list for every device attached to the system, and I want different visual states for those devices that are working properly, not working, busy, etc etc

Comment: @javirs and does every device is represented with same visual in ListBox when all are working properly? Yes or no? and second question is for the bool we are taking about, does it represents the machine(s) state?

Comment: yes, all the devices have exactly the same properties and the same look and feel when they are working ok. Then I have different visual states for "broken state" (should be triggered by bool) and a different state for the currently selected (that can change the visualstate either from the ListBox (if there's a way) or, if needed, there is also a bool in the device named CurrentlySelected that I debuged and works as expected.

Comment: @javirs see my updated answer, please let me know if i missed any part. An important part of output would be how much you want to change the visual on device state change, i just use background color.

Comment: you are setting a background property, I would like to change the visual state including the animations I set for those visual state change in the states panel of Blend. I move labels position and change shadows and others, fairly more complex. Is there a way to set the visual state?

Comment: @javirs sorry, it took me a little time to get this attended. please see my update in answer where I'm changing the visual state on basis of a bind property. please let me know if something is still incomplete.

Comment: @javirs did it help?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm hyper bussy right now, so I guess I won't be able to test untill the weekend but your code makes all the sense in the world and fits exactly what I was looking for. Im SUPER surprised that States won't change automatically with some built in stuff (behaviours?) but the ussage of the extra class will help. I will test it ASAP and I will let u know (And choose your answer)

Comment: as expected there is a way easier solution, the behavior `GoToStateAction` allows for a Trigger (that can be DataTrigger) and as consequence you can change the state of an object.. 0 code lines, 4 clicks ...  I will post a nice screenshot with the details as an answer. Any how I wanted to thank you personally for the effort you took in your answer.

Comment: @javirs your welcome, it was my learning too... and waiting for your update..... :)

Comment: I added the "method" as an answer and selected as a valid answer as is the better approach to the solution, but sent to you the 50rep anyhow. If you could upvote the answer it will appear before this thread. I think is the better for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

> I mean in the user interface of Blend, where to click to get the conditional working,

1. In Blend look for the `Objects and Timeline` panel.
2. Select the control in your defined ItemTemplate (you have set one up right?) which you want to have the state changes. *In Kylo's example above we would have selected the `TextBox`.*
3. Right click and select `Edit Style` the either create a new style (most likely) or `Edit a Copy` which works of any existing inherited styles.

[image]

From there one can work on the properties tab to change specifics. Most likely you will be working directly in the xaml to do specific operations.

[image]

---

Even though these docs for Version 2, they still apply, if nothing else can give you an overview of Blend

[Create a style resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294740.aspx)

[Style and template overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273.aspx)